# Find a non-recursive formula using Telescoping method

Tags: closed-form

[image]

I'm trying to find a closed form (non-recursive equation using telescoping method and this is what I tried. I ended up with

$$T(n) = \frac{2N}{2^{k-1}} +kN^2$$

I tried to verify this and it doesn't seem right. 
$N = 1, k = 0$ (since we allowed $N=2^k$)
$$T(1) = 1$$ but using the closed form that I found 
$$T(1) = \frac{2}{2^{-1}} + 0 = 4 $$

I've been trying to find a mistake but I'm stuck.. 
Could you give me a hint how I can improved this ? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is $n^2$, not $n$.

Comment: @martycohen  Could you specify which n you are talking about?

Comment: Oops. My comment is wrong. I did not see that you divided the whole equation by n. Anyway, I answered the question with my usual way of solving this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(n)
=4T(n/2)+n^2
$,
$T(1) = 1$.

Let $n = 2^m$.
Then
$T(2^m)
=4T(2^{m-1})+(2^m)^2
$,
$T(2^0) = 1$.

Let
$u(m)
=T(2^m)
$.

Then
$u(m)
=4u(m-1)+4^m,
u(0) = 1
$.

Dividing by $4^{m}$,
this becomes
$\frac{u(m)}{4^m}
=\frac{u(m-1)}{4^{m-1}}+1,
u(0) = 1
$.

Let
$v(m) = \frac{u(m)}{4^m}$.
Then
$v(m) = v(m-1)+1,
v(0) = 1$.

This is easily seen to imply that
$v(m) = m+1$.

To see this,
write it as
$v(m)-v(m-1) = 1$.
Summing this from $1$ to $m$,
the left side gives
(here's the telescoping)
$\sum_{k=1}^m (v(k)-v(k-1))
=v(m)-v(0)
$
and the right side gives
$\sum_{k=1}^m1
=m
$,
so
$v(m)-v(0) = m$
or,
since
$v(0) = 1$,
$v(m) = m+1$.

Unwinding,
$u(m) = 4^mv(m)
= (m+1)4^m
$
and then
$T(2^m)
=u(m)
= (m+1)4^m
$.

If
$n = 2^m$,
then
$m = \log_2 n$
and
$4^m = n^2$,
so
$T(n)
=(m+1)4^m
=(1+\log_2n)n^2
$.

As a check,

$\begin{array}\\
4T(n/2)+n^2
&=4((1+\log_2(n/2))(n/2)^2)+n^2\\
&=4((1+\log_2n-\log_22)n^2/4)+n^2\\
&=(1+\log_2n-1)n^2)+n^2\\
&=(\log_2n)n^2+n^2\\
&=(1+\log_2n)n^2\\
&=T(n)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Okay. This seems clear, but would this be considered as telescoping method? I thought telescoping method should continuously cancel each other element until you get down to two that don't get canceled out.

Comment: Yes. I "hid" the telescoping when I went from $v(m)=v(m-1)+1$ to $v(m) = m+1$. I will expand my answer more fully.

Comment: Ah, okay I see it. Thank you for your help!